# Loop not ending when it is supposed to

Tags: java

I am trying to get my loop to end when the user inputs the character N or n but when I run my program it will not end properly. It seems like the char for answer isn't being read by the loop itself so can someone please help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4_Baker
  {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    char answer;
    System.out.println("=============");
    System.out.println("Prime or Not?");
    System.out.println("=============");

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a whole number ==>");
        int n = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println();

        if(isPrime(n))
        {
            System.out.println(n + " is a prime number.");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println(n + " is a composite number.");
        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Do another (Y/N)==>");
        answer = s.next().charAt(0);

    }while(answer != 'N'|| answer != 'n');

}

public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if (n%i==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

my code will not end when it is supposed to

Answer (score 1):

It should be `while(answer != 'N' && answer != 'n');`. With `while(answer != 'N' || answer != 'n');`, if somebody inputs `N` then it will continue because `answer` is equal to `N` but it is not equal to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while(answer != 'N' && answer != 'n');
```

You want the case where the character is NOT EQUAL to 'N' AND is also NOT EQUAL to 'n'

Comment: Indeed.  A very easy mistake that leads to nasty bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in the loop condition.

```
while(answer != 'N' || answer != 'n')
```

The condition above will always be true.

Use this instead:

```
while(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
```

Answer (score -2):

You try to compare String with Char in your while lopp statement.
Convert your char to int and use unicode table to look up charcode, ex. n would be 110

Before your loop:

```
int a = 0;
```

Whithin your loop:

```
a = (int)answer;
...(while a != 110 || ...)
```

Comment: edit: forget my answer its acutally wrong!
Char is single character and string multiple

Comment: Maybe delete you answer then.